# OnClick does not work

Tags: javascript

this code does not work? When i try to click on the radiobutton, nothing happens. It is supposed that it is going to be disabled but nothing is disabled and enabled. Here is the code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function ann() 
{
document.getElementById('butta').disabled = true;
document.getElementById('strup').disabled = true;
document.getElementById('name').disabled = false;
}


function own() 
{
document.getElementById('butta').disabled = false;
document.getElementById('strup').disabled = false;
document.getElementById('name').disabled = true;
}

</script>


<input type="radio" name="checktype" id="ann" onclick="ann()" value="1"> Anime<br>
<input type="radio" name="checktype" id="own" onclick="own()" value="2"> My picture<br>
```

Comment: When I read the subject line of this question, I think to myself "Select isn't broken".

Comment: Do you get any errors in your javascript console? (most browsers have one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[It Works fine](http://jsbin.com/ijexa)**

add **/edit** to the URL to inspect the code and play around.

I closed the input and break elements in the example. Although the code works without these, I would consider it good practice to close them.

EDIT:

**[Updated example](http://jsbin.com/uxupa)**

This is to demonstrate that the code does work when you have a `<select id="name">`, `<input type="file" id="strup" />` and `<input type="button" id="butta" />` in the page. Works fine in Firefox 3 and IE 7.

There must be a problem elsewhere in the code

Comment: yup, the functions fires. But the ID i wish to get disabled does not disable. And those who are supposed to enable didn't

Comment: in the example, there are no elements matching those ids. The example uses the same code as you have posted above. What type of elements are you wishing to disable i.e. what type of elements are those with ids= "butta", "strup" and "name"?

Comment: "name" is a <select id="...
"strup" is a input type file
"butta" is a input type button

Answer (score 4):

Your ids for the radio buttons are wrong.

Comment: No, they aren't.  His functions are referring to DOM elements that aren't in his code sample.

Comment: Then you can't know that they are or are not. With the knowledge of the problem that we have, this answer is very likely correct.

Answer (score 1):

This code is working!

1. Objects you are referencing to from functions are non-existent: butta, strup, name. Most possible, you have objects with this *names*, not *id's*. This is often mistake.
2. If you are unable to get javascript working at all this means only one - you may have syntax error somewhere.

One advice for future - use Firefox with Firebug add-on. This will save you your precious time.

Answer (score 0):

That code is fine.  Check the Firefox error console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>) when the page loads for possible sources of problems that might interfere with your functions being defined, and check it again after you've clicked on one of your radio buttons.  If this isn't educational, try adding `alert()`s to `ann()` and `own()` so you can determine for certain whether they're being called at all.

Comment: Your text for "Ctrl + Shift + J" is neat!  How'd you do that?

Comment: I did just that and now I saw this:

ann is not a function
own is not a function

That's the only error i get.

Comment: @Pete - use the <kbd> element to wrap the word you want to display as a keyboard input

Comment: @William: Okay, so `ann()` and `own()` aren't getting defined as functions.  The reason this is happening is probably something in the broader context of the page (something making your script tag not work?  your script tag being inside an HTML comment?) that we can't see.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that your IDs and your functions have the same name. Some browsers put HTML node IDs as properties into the global JavaScript scope. In such browsers, `ann` is basically the same as `document.getElementById('ann')`.

Try renaming either your IDs or your functions so they do not share the same name. Something like this:

```
function annClick() 
{
document.getElementById('butta').disabled = true;
document.getElementById('strup').disabled = true;
document.getElementById('name').disabled = false;
}


function ownClick() 
{
document.getElementById('butta').disabled = false;
document.getElementById('strup').disabled = false;
document.getElementById('name').disabled = true;
}

</script>


<input type="radio" name="checktype" id="ann" onclick="annClick()" value="1"> Anime<br>
<input type="radio" name="checktype" id="own" onclick="ownClick()" value="2"> My picture<br>
```

Comment: THAT almost did it! However now the problem is that only butta is being enabled when i click the ownClick()

Comment: So annClick works as expected, but ownClock only executes the first line? Are any JavaScript errors reported?